# laravel tinker when inserting to db

Tags: laravel, migration

I am creating a new web app where I have 3 tables: `users`, `teams` and `project`:

Here is the `team` and `project` migrations structure:

```php
Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('team_image', 15);
    $table->string('team_name', 50);
    $table->string('team_description');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('project', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('members')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('members')->references('id')->on('teams');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('description');
    $table->string('lead');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Here are the `Team` and `Project` models:

```php
class Team extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'teams';

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Project');
    }
}

class Project extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'project';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'description'];

    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Team');
    }
}
```

In tinker I run this:

```php
$team = factory('App\Team')->create();
```

And I got populated to db the faker mumbo jumbo and thats okay. But when I try to call the project:

```php
$team->projects()->create(['name'=>'project 1', 'description'=>'bla bla']);
```

I get this:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]:
>   Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'team_id' in 'field list' (SQL:
>   insert into `project` (`name`, `description`, `team_id`, `updated_at`,
>   `created_at`) values (project 1, bla bla, 2, 2015-12-20 00:06:29,
>   2015-12-20 00:06:29))'

And the `team_id` was used instead of `members`, used in a few migrations earlier, but I have reseted migrations and updated the migration file and rerun the migrations and db is fine, the `members` column is created.

When I replace `members` with `team_id`, then tinker works and inserts the name to the `project` table.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

The relation code doesn't know any database level information, such as foreign key constraints. That's because migrations are only used to create the tables, they have no connection to the actual models.

Instead, a standard naming convention is used by relations for foreign keys. It is made up of the lowercased name of the related model (in your case `team`) to which the string `_id` is appended. Thus it ends up with `team_id`, that's why it works when the column is named that way. If you want the foreign key column to have a non standard name (such as `members`) you need to specify that when defining the relationship:

```php
class Team extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'teams';

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Project', 'members');
    }
}
```

The Laravel Documentation on [one-to-many relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) explains that when needed you can pass two more parameters to the `hasMany` method, the foreign key and the local key column names.

Comment: Thanks Bogdan, i needed more reading so this helped me a lot and solved the problem. tnx